# Scale Down to Peak Points

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, transforms

I made this model of a bulb but didn't save the blender file:

[image]

I tried to remake it now, and honestly have no idea how I managed to make those pointy edges at the top last time.

This is my current model:

[image]

I tried to scale down the entire ring that is highlighted but it just closes up the mesh.
Trying to select each segment and scale it down on its own manually doesn't sound like a practical solution to me.
Is there a way to adjust the entire level so it would know to make each of the peaks there more pointy?